# Django choice field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a form that user can select her/his company from a choicefield. But this choicefield should contains another model's field.

What I mean:

**models.py**

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    comp_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    comp_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    comp_name = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE) #select from CompanyProfile
    comp_id = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

**forms.py**

```
companies = [] #problem is here


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    comp_name = forms.CharField(label='What is your company name?', widget=forms.Select(choices=companies))
    comp_username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('comp_name', 'comp_username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

How can I select company name from CompanyProfile?

Comment: Do you want the choice to be from every comp_name in db ?

Comment: @BriseBalloches Yes

Comment: You can retrieve such values with ```CompanyProfile.objects.values(comp_name)```, after you'll need to put it so it works in a forms.Select object.